# 24 hour analog clock problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all instances on a 24 hour analog clock where if the hour and minute hands are interchanged we get a valid time.

Solution:

Let the position of the hour and minute hands be measured clockwise in degrees from the vertical.

Let:

```
    X  =  position of hour hand

  24X  =  position of minute hand  (mod 360)
```

After interchanging the hour and minute hands:

```
  24X  =  position of hour hand    (mod 360) 

 576X  =  position of minute hand  (mod 360)  =  X
```

We seek all solutions to:

```
     X  =  576X (mod 360)

     0  =  575X (mod 360)

     X  =  (360/575)N; N  =  0, 1, 2, …, 574
```

Comment: What would - not so long ago - have been "a clock" is now apparently  "a 12-hour analog clock".